# Greatest possible width for textbox

Tags: css

I have a something similar to:

```
<div>
some text some text <input type="text" /> some text some text.
</div>
```

I want everything to be on one line but I want the textbox to be as large (width) as possible. The problem is that I don't know the length of the text on both side (it changes on each page).

How can I do this with css? (width: 100% does not work)

Comment: Do you mean textbox should grow according to text?

Comment: Yes, I want the textbox to be as large as possible.

Comment: What does as large as possible mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Couldn't figure out a way to do this without using javascript. Change the width of `div` and see how the input resizes.

http://jsfiddle.net/blackpla9ue/TzpDW/2/

Comment: Thanks! I'll wait to see if there's a solution with only CSS.